# window.parent.PostMessage is Not working for LWC with VF in iframe

Tags: lightning-web-components, stripe, postmessage

I am working on an integration application where I have a requirement to use VF within LWC and VF will send some data to LWC. I am using window.postMessage to send the Data to LWC but LWC is not receiving anything and no error is being thrown.

here is my VF code. I am using Stripe.js on my VF page.

```
<script>
    let stripe = Stripe('pk_test_XXXXXXXXXX');
    let elements = stripe.elements();
    
    window.onload = function(){
        let cardElement = elements.create('card');
        
        cardElement.mount('#card-element');

        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            stripe.createToken(cardElement).then(function(result) {
                if (result.error) {
                    
                } else {
                    
                    stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
                }
            });
        });

        function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
            window.confirm(' Sending data to LWC ');
            
            var lexOrigin = '{!lexOrigin}';
            const payload = {
                tokenInfo : token
            }
            window.parent.postMessage( payload, lexOrigin );
            window.console.log(' token ', token );

        }
    }
</script>
```

This console is printing in my debug log
window.console.log(' token ', token );

And here is my LWC code

```
connectedCallback(){
    window.addEventListener("message", this.handleMessage.bind(this));
}
handleMessage(message){
    window.console.log( JSON.stringify ( message ) );
    if (message.origin === this.vfOrigin.data) {
        this.receivedMessage = message.data;
        window.console.log(' this.receivedMessage ', this.receivedMessage );
    }
}
```

Please help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use [Lightning Message Service](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-message-service/documentation) instead.

Comment: Note LMS won't work if you have your vf inside an iframe!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are posting the PostMessage to the right domain! I would double-check the domain `{!lexOrigin}` to make sure it is populating the right domain as the top URL.

The right domain for the LWC from iframe vf would be below the URL obtained via the apex as shown below

```
public string lexOrigin {get{ return URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm().split('\\.')[0] + '.lightning.force.com';} set;}
```

You can try posting to the `*` domain and then troubleshoot backward to make sure you have posted message to right domain

Also, one more improvement you can do is not use the `bind` while listening to the window message. It is an antipattern as documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_lifecycle_hooks_dom).

Change it to the below code,

```
connectedCallback(){
   window.addEventListener("message", this.handleMessage);
}

handleMessage = (message) => {
   if (message.origin === this.vfOrigin.data) {
      this.receivedMessage = message.data;
      window.console.log(' this.receivedMessage ', this.receivedMessage );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have double-checked the value for the lexOrigin variable and it's the same

Comment: I was able to make it work after removing window.console.log( JSON.stringify ( message ) ); line from the handleMessage method.

Comment: Why would that cause it to fail?